How to manage user redirection after logout and login in Next.js based on previous route?
Body:
I'm building a Next.js application where I need to manage user redirections differently based on their authentication status and their actions (like logging out or logging in). Specifically, I face two main scenarios:

After Logout: When a user logs out, especially from a specific page such as /users, they should be redirected to the dashboard (/dashboard) upon logging back in, regardless of the previous page they were on.

After Direct URL Access (When Not Authenticated): If a user tries to directly access a route like /users without being authenticated, they are redirected to the login page. After successful login, they should be redirected back to the intended page (/users).


I am currently using custom middleware in Next.js for authentication checks, but I'm having trouble ensuring the right redirection behavior in these scenarios. Here is the code for my middleware and sign-out component:
Guest.js:
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/session'; // Adjust the path accordingly
import Preloader from '@/components/base/preloader';

const Guest = ({ children }) => {
    const { push, asPath } = useRouter();
    const { isAuthenticated, nextURL, scopes } = useAuth({
        required: false,
        onAuthenticated() {
            const hasScope =
                scopes.includes('super-admin') ||
                scopes.includes(nextURL?.slice(1).replaceAll('/', '-'));
            if (scopes.length && !hasScope && nextURL != '/dashboard') {
                const baseAccess = ['system-admin', 'admin-access'];
                const redirectTo = scopes?.find(value => !baseAccess.includes(value));
                push(redirectTo);
            }
            if ((nextURL ? nextURL : '/dashboard') !== asPath && hasScope) {
                push(nextURL ? nextURL : '/dashboard');
            }
        },
    });
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return children;
    }
    return <Preloader />;
}

export default Guest;
`

**auth.js**:
```javascript
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Preloader from '@/components/base/preloader';
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/session'; // Adjust the path accordingly

const AuthMiddleware = ({ children }) => {
    const { push, asPath } = useRouter();
    const { isAuthenticated, setNextURL } = useAuth({
        required: true,
        onUnauthenticated() {
            setNextURL(asPath);
            if (asPath !== '/') {
                push('/');
            }
        },
    });
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return children;
    }
    return <Preloader />;
}

export default AuthMiddleware``
`

**Signout Component**:
```javascript
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Button from '@/components/custom/button';
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/session';

const Signout = () => {
    const { push } = useRouter();
    const { authToken, removeAuthToken } = useAuth();

    const handleSignOut = useCallback(() => {
        removeAuthToken();
        push('/');
    }, [removeAuthToken, push]);

    return <Button onClick={handleSignOut}>Sign out</Button>;
}
```

### Questions:

1. How can I ensure that after a user logs out and logs back in, they are redirected to the dashboard, instead of being taken back to the last page they were on?
2. How can I make sure that if a user accesses a URL directly and is unauthenticated, they are redirected to that specific URL after logging in?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly manage these redirections based on the user's previous actions and authentication status in Next.js.

---

Expected Results:
I expected that after logging out and logging back in, users would be redirected to /dashboard regardless of the previous page they were on. Additionally, when a user directly accesses a protected page and logs in, they should be redirected back to that specific page.

